# Why \usepackage{fontspec} is being ignored on Miktex on Windows?

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, fontspec, windows

I installed all Miktex packages. but as soon as I use

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Helvetica Neue}
```

where Helvetica Neue ttf file is installed system‑wide on Windows, the font being output in the pdf is LMroman whereas if I compile the same tex file with TexLive on Linux, the generated pdf is written using the expected font.
The same thing happens with Xetex and happens with all documents classes. Even asking to print a single letter is enough to trigger the issue.

The [Windows/MikTex log doesn’t contain any warning nor info about the selected font](https://pastebin.com/R3wE72T3) (Helvetica Neue).
Could it be because the way MiKTeX works differently from TexLive?

Comment: I can’t use TexLive on Windows because I’m using a version of Windows server where the 32‑bits subsystem is disabled and TexLive is 32‑bits only on Windows at least at install time.

Comment: make a small but complete example and then show it together with its log-file (at best from lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would say that prompting \begin and add a single letter to print to the example of the beginning triggers the issue. **It happens with all documents classes**

Comment: if you want my help, do as I say: show the example and the log.

Comment: As I said, you can just remove all infos about the current log of the post about the used classes in order to use the result. **Since compiling the exact same document on Linux doesn t triggers the issue, then the problem isn t the document but something like an Install time option**.

Comment: You seem to know better than me what is needed to investigate your problem, so I think you will be able to solve it alone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no but I said it happens in general and not just with a specific document.

Comment: this doesn't matter. To compare the logs I need a log of a specific document. So create a small example (the smaller the better), compile with lualatex and show the example and the log-file (not the terminal output!).